# ERROR NG8001: ReadyToTalkComponent is not a known element - Already Declared in NgModule Angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

After upgrading the version to Angular 14, I encountered a lot of errors. Most of them were not known element. The component name was already declared under @NgModule in Declarations. Please see the contents below.

`ng version`

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.11
Node: 14.20.1
Package Manager: npm 6.14.17 
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 14.3.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.11
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.11
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.8
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.8
@angular/cdk                    14.2.7
@angular/cli                    14.2.11
@angular/fire                   7.5.0
@angular/material               14.2.7
@ngtools/webpack                14.2.11
@nguniversal/express-engine     14.2.3
@schematics/angular             15.2.8
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.8.4
```

**shared.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {ReadyToTalkComponent} from './common/ready-to-talk/ready-to-talk.component';

@NgModule({
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  imports: [SOME_MODULES_HERE],
  declarations: [ ReadyToTalkComponent ],
  exports: [ ReadyToTalkComponent ]
})

export class SharedModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { SharedModule } from './shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SOME_COMPONENTS],
  imports: [ SharedModule ],
  providers: [SOME_SERVICES],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**webinar.component.html**

```html
<app-ready-to-talk></app-ready-to-talk>
```

**ready-to-talk.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ready-to-talk',
  templateUrl: './ready-to-talk.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ready-to-talk.component.scss']
})
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
Error: src/app/webinar/webinar.component.html:148:1 - error NG8001: 'app-ready-to-talk' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-ready-to-talk' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-ready-to-talk' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I'm not really sure if putting `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` under **app.module.ts** will solve the problem since it was already in Shared Module.

Thank you!

EDITED:
When I set the `"aot": false` in **angular.json**, the error above didn't show.

Comment: I am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

This might sound obvious but I fell into this trap after upgrading Angular, firstly have you made sure there are no issues in the ready-to-talk component itself? As this can cause that error.

The next thing is have you restarted the CLI since fixing all those other issues? If not, try shutting down VSCode and re-loading your project

Comment: I already did it and ready-to-talk component does not have any problems.

Comment: ah ok, do you have the webinar.component imported into the shared module?

Comment: It's on app.module.ts

Comment: @JasonJavier You should probably edit your post to show that `app.module` declares `webinar.component`. It's a pretty important piece.

Answer (score 0):

I may not recommend this solution but setting the `"aot": false` in **angular.json** file eliminates the error.